# A bit about 'interest'

Tags: meaning-in-context

Is it right sentence:

> I had to leave just as the conversation was getting **interest**.

What is the 'interest' here? What does it mean?

If it's right, why don't say instead of it:

> I had to leave just as the conversation was getting **interesting**.

Comment: In this context, if you think of *to get* as meaning *to **become*** (as in *"I'm getting tired of explaining this"*), you'll see you need a "quality, attribute", not a simple noun.

Comment: It seems likely to me that this is an error and should be written the way you have it. Technically, the first sentence is grammatical and could be interpreted as relaxing suggests, but the more natural way of expressing that would be ". . .just as the conversation was starting to interest people in the room." The phrase would be annoyingly misleading otherwise because (as you notice) the ear expects "interesting" at the end of the sentence. When in doubt, assume people are trying to talk about themselves and what interests _them._

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean that the conversation elicited the interest of the audience, the correct word is undoubtedly "interesting". I can't see "interest" fitting in that sentence at that position in any case, or that I can't think of any.

Cut out the clause from the sentence -

> The conversation was getting ***interesting***.

Ask the question - How the conversation was getting? The answer of this question is something that modifies the subject "conversation", and we call those words "adjective". So we need an adjective after "getting" in that sentence.

"interest" is a verb, while "interesting" is an adjective. So the correct form is "interesting".

Comment: I agree with you. However, I managed to think of this rephrasing, where the noun form would be okay: _I had to leave just as the conversation was capturing **my** interest._

Comment: @J.R. Yes you are right about it. But in your case the verb is different (capture) :)

Comment: If "interest" was read as a noun, I would have imagined a lecture on Finance. :)

Comment: @Man_From_India - I suppose you could say "getting my interest", but I thought _capturing_ sounded better. Another possibility would be _gaining_.

Comment: @J.R. Correct. I agree.

Answer (score 1):

If you meant to imply that the conversation had begun to catch the attention of people in the room (who would then come over and listen or respond), you could say "I had to leave just as the conversation was attracting interest."

Otherwise, the latter is certainly more correct.

Comment: ok, but I still don't see why 'interest', not 'interesting'

Comment: @Selio Because in the case of "getting interesting", *interesting* is an adjective (*interesting conversation*). "Getting" is used in the sense of "becoming". By changing to "attracting interest", *interest* is now a noun.

Comment: @Selio I think it was a mistake. This is a possible way to suggest that the conversation was garnering ("getting") the interest of people nearby, but it sounds strange and is probably not how anyone would say this--even in the unlikely case that this is what they were trying to say.